# HTTP Request From Incontact Studio Script

Tags: http, restful-url

I am using Incontact studio for real time calling and processing for the call. I need to send callback to my system on call disposition in the studio. Can anyone give me a way to make http request from the script?

Answer (score 3):

inContact developer portal (https://developer.incontact.com/) will have additional details, but in a nutshell here's how you can achieve a request via script:

```
DYNAMIC d
d.params = "yourParams"
ASSIGN jsonParams = "{d.asjson()}"

ASSIGN url = "yourUrl"
ASSIGN req = GetRESTProxy()
req.ContentType = "application/json"
ASSIGN result = req.MakeRestRequest(url, jsonParams, 0, "POST")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you have two options

**First**, in the Studio you can create an Snippet for your API, the Studio supports usage for Webservices considering use REST or SOAP.
Check Bellow some links, I thinks may help you

- [Supported Web Services](https://help.nice-incontact.com/content/studio/scripts/reference/webservices.htm?TocPath=Studio%7CStudio%7CScripts%7CScripting%20Reference%20Material%7C_____6)
- [Enable Analytics-based Text Routing](https://help.incontact.com/fall19/EN/Content/InteractionAnalyticsPro/ConfigurationAndAdministration/TextBasedRouting/EnableAnalyticsBasedTextRouting.htm?TocPath=Analytics%20And%20Reporting%7CInteraction%20Analytics%20Pro%7CConfiguration%20And%20Administration%7CText%20Based%20Routing%7C_____1)

**Second** Approach, you can try consume Nice InContact REST APIs, but you will need apply those configurations on CXOne Administrator platform for which API that you wanted to use,  AND consuming those apis, you also need a "Nice token", they has three options for generate token, choose what is the best for your system.
Check Bellow the documentation for it [Explore NICE inContact REST APIs](https://developer.niceincontact.com/API)